# Can't install global packages with sudo, only su works

Tags: npm

I have Node and NPM installed.

```
$ node -v
v0.10.25

$ npm -v
1.3.24
```

As a regular user, if I try to install a global package, I get a permission error:

```
$ npm -g install grunt-cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/bin/grunt'
npm ERR! error rolling back  grunt-cli@0.1.13 { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/bin/grunt'] errno: 3, code: 'EACCES', path: '/usr/local/bin/grunt' }
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/bin/grunt'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/bin/grunt'] errno: 3, code: 'EACCES', path: '/usr/local/bin/grunt' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

Fair enough, let me use `sudo`:

```
$ sudo npm -g install grunt-cli
/usr/local/bin/grunt -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt
grunt-cli@0.1.13 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli
├── resolve@0.3.1
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.4)
└── findup-sync@0.1.2 (lodash@1.0.1, glob@3.1.21)
```

Looks good, but now if I try to use my newly-installed package, I can't:

```
$ grunt
fs.js:695
  return binding.readlink(pathModule._makeLong(path));
                 ^
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/usr/local/bin/grunt'
    at Object.fs.readlinkSync (fs.js:695:18)
    at Object.realpathSync (fs.js:1283:25)
    at tryFile (module.js:142:15)
    at Function.Module._findPath (module.js:181:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:25)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

Frustrating. But, if I uninstall `sudo npm -g uninstall grunt-cli` and then try again by fully switching to root, it works:

```
$ sudo su -
root# npm -g install grunt-cli
/usr/local/bin/grunt -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt
grunt-cli@0.1.13 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli
├── resolve@0.3.1
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.4)
└── findup-sync@0.1.2 (lodash@1.0.1, glob@3.1.21)

^D

$ grunt
grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface. (v0.1.13)
```

This happens for all global packages (grunt, supervisor, etc) and is incredibly frustrating. Why does `sudo` fail, but `su` work? What can I do to fix my environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess, its probably umask -- you probably have `077`, while root's default is something like `022`.  So with sudo, created files are not world readable, but with su they are.

What are the permissions/ownership on the file /usr/local/bin/grunt when you install with sudo vs when installed with su?

Comment: Interesting. My umask is `0027`. The root umask is `0022`. Installing via `sudo`:

    root# ls -l /usr/local/bin/grunt 
    lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel

And via `su`:

    $ ls -l /usr/local/bin/grunt
    lrwxr-x---  1 root  wheel

So I guess because I am not a member of the wheel group, I can't run the scripts? What's the safest way to fix this?

Comment: @Ryan: I think you listed them backwards -- with `sudo` it isn't world readable.  So you need do something like `( umask 022; sudo npm ... )`, running npm in a subshell with a different umask.  Or perhaps npm has some configuration option to change the umask.

Comment: Thanks @chris, I did indeed have them backward. Apparently NPM has a umask config option, but I couldn't get it to stick, so I changed my umask to `022`, which solves to problem.

Comment: Sorry for the noobis but I don't get how to fix this :( I am on debian and I created manually my non root user, installed npm -g install grunt-cli but I can't use grunt from cli... Can you please explain better?

Comment: @Pitto: run `umask 022` to set the umask /before/ running `sudo npm -g install grunt-cli`